# Which tool is used by the doctrine ORM project to automatically tag release versions?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, semantic-versioning

i.e. https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/releases

> v2.2.4
>
> Total issues resolved: 7
>   etc. etc.

PS. I'm not asking about the css style, but the version number, commit number and commit messages

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for a while i found it:
https://github.com/weierophinney/changelog_generator